# Picking phrases containing specific words in python

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, any

I have a list with 10 names and a list with many of phrases. I only want to select the phrases containing one of those names.

```
ArrayNames = [Mark, Alice, Paul]
ArrayPhrases = ["today is sunny", "Paul likes apples", "The cat is alive"]
```

In the example, is there any way to pick only the second phrase considering the face that contains Paul, given these two arrays?
This is what I tried:

```
def foo(x,y):
tmp = []
for phrase in x:
    if any(y) in phrase:
        tmp.append(phrase)     
print(tmp)
```

x is the array of phrases, y is the array of names.
This is the output:

```
    if any(y) in phrase:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, bool found
```

I'm very unsure about the syntax I used concerning the any() construct. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) is incorrect, do the following:

```
ArrayNames = ['Mark', 'Alice', 'Paul']
ArrayPhrases = ["today is sunny", "Paul likes apples", "The cat is alive"]

result = []
for phrase in ArrayPhrases:
    if any(name in phrase for name in ArrayNames):
        result.append(phrase)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['Paul likes apples']
```

You are getting a [TypeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) because any returns a bool and your trying to search for a bool inside a string (`if any(y) in phrase:`).

Note that `any(y)` works because it will use the *truthy* value of each of the strings of `y`.

Comment: It works now, but do you think this is the most efficient way? I have to scan an entire document, do I need my script to be as efficient as possible. I'm open to different solutions!

Comment: @IanWing to speed up things you would need to use a specific data structure (perhaps a trie) but that is a different question. I recommend you look up flashtext